# Recurrent Neural network classification

Tags: r, recurrent-neural-network

I want to use R recurrent neural network package `rnn` to classify polarity of aspect and sentiment pairs. for example, the inputs are pre-trained embedding of word "speed" and "fast", I expect to get a class label of this pair by RNN classification.

Could you give me some instruction about using the `rnn` package for this task?
What the input `X` and out `Y` of the `trainr()` method should be?

Answer (score 0):

A first place to look would be at the documentation of the package using:

```
library(rnn)
help(rnn)
```

This page refers to the two main functions of the package `trainr()` and `predictr()`

The `trainr()` help page describes the form of the inputs, which should be numeric arrays. For classes you should thus transform your `character` data to `factor` using `as.factor()`.

The help page also gives and example. For long form examples have a look at:

```
vignette('rnn')
```

and

```
vignette('sinus')
```

You can also find the vignettes on the [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rnn).